# How to combine 2 isotope filter javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, filtering, jquery-isotope

Hi I have successfully setup isotope filtering with multiple drop downs using this js code -

```
jQuery(function() {
    var $container = $('#isocontent'),
        $select = $('div#filterGroup select');
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });
    $select.change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var $optionSet = $this;
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
        filters[group] = $this.find('option:selected').attr('data-filter-value');

        var isoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in filters) {
            isoFilters.push(filters[prop])
        }
        var selector = isoFilters.join('');

        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

And on the same page I was able to setup a live search input field using the quicksearch.js plugin and isotopes by using this code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('input#id_search').quicksearch('#isocontent.box');
});
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

   var $container = $('#isocontent');


   $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });


    $('input#filter').quicksearch('#isocontent .box', {
        'show': function() {
            $(this).addClass('quicksearch-match');
        },
        'hide': function() {
            $(this).removeClass('quicksearch-match');
        }
    }).keyup(function(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $container.isotope({ filter: '.quicksearch-match' }).isotope(); 
        }, 100 );
    });

});
 </script>
```

The live search and drop downs work, except they are not working together. When doing a search, it will find the content as should - hiding the irrelevant content- but when filtering with the drop downs, it seems to reset or ignore the filtering done by the live search. Is there away to get the two functions to work together and possibly combine the script into one script??

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i have done it.

First, I register a simple text filter.

Then in case a button is clicked, I "extend" this filter by redefining it (by passing a function to isotope's filter option).

If no button is clicked, I re-register the simple text filter.

**Isotope initialization:**

```
var qsRegex; // global variable

var $grid = $(container).isotope({
    resizable: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: columnWidth
    },
    filter: function() {
        return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    }
});
```

**Then my keyup event on the input:**

```
var tabPane = $('.tab-pane.active');
var $quicksearch = tabPane.find('.quicksearch').unbind().keyup( debounce( function() {

    qsRegex = new RegExp($quicksearch.val(), 'gi');
    $grid.isotope();

}, 200 ) );
```

**Then my click event on the buttons:**
*(simplified)*

The addition of *$(this).hasClass(filter)* is what is important here.

```
$('.gender-switch').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
        var filter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        var my_combined_filter = function() {
            return qsRegex ? ($(this).text().match( qsRegex ) && $(this).hasClass(filter))  : true;
        }
        $('.tab-pane.active .gallery').isotope({ filter: my_combined_filter });
    } else {
        // none of the buttons have been selected.
        // reset to the simple filter
        $('.tab-pane.active .gallery').isotope({ filter: '*' });
        var my_simple_filter = function() {
            return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
        }
        $('.tab-pane.active .gallery').isotope({ filter: my_simple_filter });
    }
});
```

**Extra: the debounce function in the keyup event**

```
// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    return function debounced() {
        if ( timeout ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        function delayed() {
            fn();
            timeout = null;
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
    }
}
```